# Why can't I merge arrays using array_merge()?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm unsuccessfully trying to merge arrays. An array looks like this:

```
//var_dump()
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(Brand)[177]
      (...)
  1 => 
    object(Brand)[271]
      (...)
```

This is the code I use:

```
        $premiumBrands = array();

        foreach ($stores as $store) :
            $brands = getBrands($store->brands);

            echo count($brands['premium']).', ';

            if(count($brands['premium']) > 0) {
                array_merge($premiumBrands,$brands['premium']);
            }
        endforeach;

        echo count(premiumBrands);
```

The result of the output in the loop is this: `2, 0, 0, 1, 0`;
The result of the last output is this: `0`;

Using

```
$premiumBrands = $premiumBrands + $brands['premium'];
```

will not work, because all arrays starts with an index key of [0] - so it will just overwrite `premiumBrands`

So how can I merge my arrays?

And yes, I've read [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). Still can't solve it.

Comment: `$premiumBrands = array_merge(..)`?

Comment: `$premiumBrands = array_merge($premiumBrands, $brands['premium']);`? `array_merge` returns a new array, it does not alter the existing ones. Read the docs - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Just a typo. It is $premiumBrands.

Comment: Yes @Bjorn, I've read the docs. Even tried `$premiumBrands + $brands['premium']`. See updated Q.

Comment: @Steven don't get snippy with Bjorn because he's dead on ;). You are missing his point. You are discarding the result of the operation.

Comment: @Steven, You are not setting the `array_merge()` result to a new variable. You need `$premiumBrands = array_merge(..)`, like they are telling you

Comment: @Steven, you can't sum up arrays as you're trying to do in your updated question. Just replace the line with the code I gave you. The point you're missing is that `array_merge` returns a fresh array, but you have to assign it to a variable to keep it. `array_merge` does _not_ alter any array you give it.

Comment: Yeah, I see it now. Just to tired to notice the `$premiumBrands =`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the new array to a variable. The new array will contain the merged arrays which you can merge over and over in a loop. It all depends on what your keys and values are to get it to work the way you want, but the documentation is clear http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
    $premiumBrands = array();

    foreach ($stores as $store) :
        $brands = getBrands($store->brands);

        echo count($brands['premium']).', ';

        if(count($brands['premium']) > 0) {
            $premiumBrands = array_merge($premiumBrands,$brands['premium']); /// *** ///
        }
    endforeach;

    echo count(premiumBrands);
```

Comment: Of course. At the end of the day my brain is mush and I thought `array_merge` did that job for me. #shouldnotworkwhentired

Comment: PHP is dirty like that. Some functions return the result, others manipulate the parameters, but in most cases, the result is returned.